# can't specify dtype when creating pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I can't seem to get the dtype parameter to the DataFrame constructor to work:
Issue described here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9133

Constructor is here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

(It does work with read_csv, --note that read_csv() actually describes how to use the dtype parameter:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

*dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} (Unsupported with engine=’python’). Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype.*
)

Has this been fixed?  Does it work for anyone?

(I know I can specify the types later with astype, but that introduces an unnecessary conversion step on potentially large amounts of data.)

Comment: AFAIK this is still an open issue...

Comment: Indeed. Workaround seems to be to do this using `numpy`.

Comment: Couldn't someone just copy and paste the working source code from read_csv() method?  Maybe it's not that easy ...